Can Gibbs Free Energy equation be used to explain why some phase changes are exothermic or endothermic?
I was wondering about some ways to explain why some phase changes are exo / endo.
I am aware that for endothermic phase changes (boiling, melting, sublimation) energy input is required to raise the potential energy of molecules as they become more disordered and further away from each other.
But, one thing I noticed is that making a system to be more disordered is a way of increasing entropy, making change in entropy to be positive.
Also, I found out that for a closed system where temperature (during a phase change, temp is constant. isn't it?) and pressure are constant, change in gibbs free energy is zero.
From the formula of gibbs free energy,
dG = dH - T dS
As dG = 0 and dS > 0 for phase changes like boiling, melting, sublimation,
I thought that dH must be positive, and that explains why those particular phase changes are endothermic, and vice versa for some exothermic phase changes.
Is my thinking right? Please let me know if there is any that I need to fix. Thanks!!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
